# Go binary, that tries to run shell command in ESXI environment is failing

Tags: linux, go, esxi

below is my code

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    sh := "/bin/sh"
    flag := "-c"
    command := "ls -l"
    fmt.Println("program is running")

    result, err := RunCmdAsText(sh, flag, command)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func RunCmdAsText(sh string, flag string, command string) (string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command(sh, flag, command)

    old := os.Stdout
    defer func() {
        os.Stdout = old
    }()
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w
    os.Stderr = w

    cmd.Stdout = w
    cmd.Stderr = w

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    outC := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        io.Copy(&buf, r)
        outC <- buf.String()
    }()

    w.Close()
    out := <-outC
    return out, nil
}
```

It basically tries to run a shell command via golang.

When I try to run it in ESXI-670, it errors with

```
program is running
fork/exec /bin/sh: no space left on device
```

Here is what I have tried:

1. I have tried doing this with cmd.Output().
2. I have tried building using CGO_ENABLED=1
3. In the code above, I have tried to run by redirecting os.Stdout.

This code works and provides desired output in all locations, other than ESXI. I am using ESXI-6.7.0.

Please help me in identifying the cause.

1. I am certain there is space left on device

Following is the output from strace:

```
execve("./hello-latest", ["./hello-latest"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x2bde2a7000
uname({sys="VMkernel", node="<redacted-Sesitive-Information>", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/tls/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64/tls", 0x3e70b20c398)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0pn\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0555, st_size=136524, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e2a7000
mmap(NULL, 2212896, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2c1e2a8000
mmap(0x2c1e2a8000, 98304, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2c1e2a8000
mmap(0x2c1e4bf000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x2c1e4bf000
mmap(0x2c1e4c1000, 13344, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e4c1000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\32\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0555, st_size=2001344, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3861664, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2c1e4c5000
mmap(0x2c1e4c5000, 1724416, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2c1e4c5000
mmap(0x2c1e86a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a5000) = 0x2c1e86a000
mmap(0x2c1e870000, 15520, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e870000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e874000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e875000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2c1e874b40)   = 0
mprotect(0x2c1e86a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x2c1e4bf000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x546000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7b5000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
set_tid_address(0x2c1e874e10)           = 3081896
set_robust_list(0x2c1e874e20, 0x18)     = 0
futex(0x3e70b20cc5c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x3e70b20cc5c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 2c1e874b40) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x2c1e2ae870, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x2c1e2ae900, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=512*1024, rlim_max=512*1024}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x2bde2a7000
brk(0x2bde2c8000)                       = 0x2bde2c8000
brk(0)                                  = 0x2bde2c8000
sched_getaffinity(0, 8192, {ffffffffffffffff, ff, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}) = 128
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/hpage_pmd_size", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e876000
mmap(NULL, 131072, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e8b6000
mmap(NULL, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e8d6000
mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e9d6000
mmap(NULL, 67108864, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1f1d6000
mmap(NULL, 536870912, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c231d6000
mmap(0xc000000000, 67108864, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc000000000
mmap(NULL, 33554432, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c431d6000
mmap(NULL, 2165776, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c451d6000
mmap(0xc000000000, 4194304, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc000000000
mmap(0x2c1e8b6000, 131072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e8b6000
mmap(0x2c1e956000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1e956000
mmap(0x2c1eddc000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c1eddc000
mmap(0x2c21206000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c21206000
mmap(0x2c33356000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2c33356000
mmap(NULL, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc004000000
mmap(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc004100000
mmap(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc004110000
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686523688}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686585418}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686667011}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686724890}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686774445}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686830404}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686882310}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686930411}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 686978253}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 687030454}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 687082256}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 687132897}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 687184643}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 687234034}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 687428100}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 687480557}) = 0
sigaltstack(NULL, {ss_sp=0, ss_flags=SS_DISABLE, ss_size=0}) = 0
sigaltstack({ss_sp=0xc000002000, ss_flags=0, ss_size=32768}, NULL) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
gettid()                                = 3081896
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [HUP], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTRAP, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTRAP, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGBUS, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGBUS, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSTKFLT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSTKFLT, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGURG, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGURG, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGIO, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGIO, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPWR, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPWR, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, NULL, {0x2c1e2ae870, [], SA_SIGINFO}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, NULL, {0x2c1e2ae870, [], SA_SIGINFO}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x2c1e2ae870, [], SA_STACK|SA_SIGINFO}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, NULL, {0x2c1e2ae900, [], SA_SIGINFO}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, NULL, {0x2c1e2ae900, [], SA_SIGINFO}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x2c1e2ae900, [], SA_STACK|SA_SIGINFO}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_2, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_3, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_3, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_4, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_4, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_5, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_5, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_6, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_6, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_7, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_7, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_8, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_8, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_9, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_9, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_10, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_10, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_11, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_11, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_12, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_12, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_13, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_13, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_14, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_14, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_15, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_15, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_16, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_16, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_17, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_17, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_18, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_18, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_19, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_19, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_20, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_20, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_21, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_21, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_22, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_22, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_23, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_23, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_24, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_24, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_25, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_25, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_26, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_26, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_27, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_27, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_28, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_28, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_29, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_29, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_30, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_30, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_31, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_31, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_32, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_32, {0x461240, ~[], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2c1e2b7db0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 528384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0xc004120000
mprotect(0xc004120000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0xc00419fff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0xc0041a09d0, tls=0xc0041a0700, child_tidptr=0xc0041a09d0) = 3081897
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 697616743}) = 0
--- SIGURG (Urgent I/O condition) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0xc0000090f0)              = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 528384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0xc0041a1000
mprotect(0xc0041a1000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0xc004220ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0xc0042219d0, tls=0xc004221700, child_tidptr=0xc0042219d0) = 3081898
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
futex(0xc0000e0950, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 698284207}) = 0
sched_yield()                           = 0
futex(0x562018, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 528384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0xc0042e3000
mprotect(0xc0042e3000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0xc004362ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0xc0043639d0, tls=0xc004363700, child_tidptr=0xc0043639d0) = 3081900
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 528384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0xc004364000
mprotect(0xc004364000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0xc0043e3ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0xc0043e49d0, tls=0xc0043e4700, child_tidptr=0xc0043e49d0) = 3081901
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 699775552}) = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x102 (flags O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY)
futex(0xc0000e0d50, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 700011558}) = 0
fcntl(1, F_GETFL)                       = 0x102 (flags O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8460115, 700112940}) = 0
fcntl(2, F_GETFL)                       = 0x102 (flags O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY)
write(1, "program is running\n", 19program is running
)    = 19
pipe2([3, 4], O_CLOEXEC)                = 0
epoll_create1(O_CLOEXEC)                = 5
pipe2([6, 7], O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC)     = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 6, {EPOLLIN, {u32=5833552, u64=5833552}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET|0x2000, {u32=69381896, u64=824703102728}}) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 4, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET|0x2000, {u32=69381896, u64=824703102728}}) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 8, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET|0x2000, {u32=69381896, u64=824703102728}}) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
pipe2([9, 10], O_CLOEXEC)               = 0
getpid()                                = 3081896
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[], NULL, 8) = 0
clone(runtime: epollwait on fd 5 failed with 38
fatal error: runtime: netpoll failed
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK|SIGCHLD) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0xc0000090f0)              = 0
--- SIGURG (Urgent I/O condition) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0xc0000090f0)              = 0
close(9)                                = 0
futex(0x561d50, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL
runtime stack:
runtime.throw({0x4bc189, 0xc00419f7b8})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1198 +0x71
runtime.netpoll(0x1e0e6e2f250b90)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll_epoll.go:131 +0x34e
runtime.sysmon()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:5404 +0x2ea
runtime.mstart1()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1407 +0x93
runtime.mstart0()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1365 +0x79
runtime.mstart()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:248 +0x5

goroutine 1 [runnable]:
syscall.Close(0xa)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_amd64.go:285 +0xbb
syscall.forkExec({0x4b8e7b, 0xc000016016}, {0xc000122150, 0x3, 0x3}, 0xa88cb7b200000200)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/exec_unix.go:213 +0x3d2
syscall.StartProcess(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/exec_unix.go:256
os.startProcess({0x4b8e7b, 0xc000132140}, {0xc000122150, 0x3, 0x3}, 0xc0000eade0)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/exec_posix.go:55 +0x332
os.StartProcess({0x4b8e7b, 0x7}, {0xc000122150, 0x3, 0x3}, 0x10)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/exec.go:109 +0x5a
os/exec.(*Cmd).Start(0xc00014c000)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/exec/exec.go:422 +0x60a
main.RunCmdAsText({0x4b8e7b, 0xc000136008}, {0x4b88f3, 0x1}, {0x4b8c0d, 0xc0000001a0})
        /hello/hello.go:43 +0x16d
main.main()
        /hello/hello.go:17 +0x85
unknown pid: 3081898
```

Comment: Does `/bin/sh -c 'ls -l'` work OK when run the same way your Go program runs? I'm asking because problems like this has to be dissected.

Comment: @kostix , yes the command you mentioned works as it should. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Do you have `strace` ([manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/1/strace)) available in that environment?

Comment: Yes, I do have ```strace``` in my environment. I have edited my Question with strace dump. Thank you.

Comment: "I am certain there is space left on device": An `ENOSPC` error in response to a `clone()` system call doesn't mean you have a full disk. There are a number of documented reasons that `clone()` may fail with `ENOSPC`, as described in [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), but it doesn't look like you're hitting one of those. I would guess that you're hitting some kind of resource limit, but I don't have an ESXI system on which to test.

Comment: Thank you @larsks, for looking into this. If this helps, I have the same program in python and C++, and they both run without any issues in the same environment.

Comment: That's why SO is not fit for such kind of questions: they require multiple backs-and-forth which is quite inconvenient to do using comments. I would recommend to repost the question to [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts) and add a summary of our comment thread. I'd also recommend to retake the `strace` capture using its `-o` command-line option so that its output is not intermixed with the Go runtime's output—as it is in your comment.

Comment: Basically, I'm with @larsks on this: the `clone` syscall on Linux underlies `fork`, and a hunch is that the Go runtime performs the fork+exec combo to run a child process using some setup which trips some limit on EXSI. So it's a question for the devs to look into; may be it even warrants filing a bug report.

Comment: …and by the way, what kernel version is there in ESXI? I'm asking because of [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21347).

Comment: @kostix, thank you for the guidance, I will do as you mentioned and post it on the mailing list

ESXI kernel version - command uname -a
VMkernel 6.7.0 #1 SMP Release build-15160138 Nov 22 2019 20:49:31 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 ESXi

Comment: Oh, looks like VMKernel of ESXi is not based on Linux; it merely provides compatibility for the drivers and implements POSIX syscalls. Hence the situation is even more interesting. If/when you post a message to the mailing list, please post a link here.

Comment: @kostix, thank you, I have posted a message in mailing list, since it is a moderted group, it might take up to 24 hours for the message to appear. I will post the link as soon as the message is posted. :)

Comment: @kostix
[ESXI Mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/R1vvk2pZW7w)

Comment: Thanks, I've just expanded on the Ian's reply there. Let's continue in that thread.

Comment: @FawnMohra did you ever find a workaround in Go? I'm having the same issue. The link to the mailing list isn't working anymore :(

Comment: Are you using VMFS5?. This FS only has 130,000 inodes available and the message that you will get when running out of inodes is ENOSPC as well.